# NodeJS server and React app can't use the same version of Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, version

Here is my problem and it might be super simple to fix, but I am new to the world of web technologies.

I have a react app that is running using node version 10.0.0. I am using npm n as my node version manager, and I am using `n stable` as my version selector.

When I try to run the NodeJS server that is supposed to accompany it, it fails when I try to run it with node version 10. I have to go back to version 4.9.1, so I can run the server without any problems.

Has anyone else faced this issue or know what it could be? If I go to a newer version of node I get a Bindings.js npm error. If I build my react app with 4.9.1, well that doesn't work at all.

To run both at the same time I have to switch to node version 4.9.1 and then run the nodeJS server, then change to version 10 and build the react app which to me is not how a production build should go.

Any thoughts?

Comment: 1. What is the exact error you're getting 2. Have you tried `rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall using node 10?

Comment: So I am using RTI DDS Connext, and when I try to install it with node 10, I get a mkdir error and a node-gyp build error. On 4.9.1 DDS works but not here. I am sudoing the npm install command but am still getting the permission error.

Comment: Can you update your question with this information? node-gyp errors are OK unless it stops your install. It's usually an optional dependency, so it shouldn't matter. "a mkdir error" doesn't really give me enough information

Comment: Side note: in my experience if you have to do `sudo npm install`, something is wrong that should be fixed.

Comment: I will post a screenshot of the errors I get from npm and I will update my question with that and some other information.